# back up logs using backupeventlog method get-wmiobject

Tags: powershell, logging, windows-server-2008, event-log

Hi I am using the below line powershell.

```
(get-wmiobject win32_nteventlogfile | Where {$_.logfilename -eq "Application"} | select-object -First 100).backupeventlog("C:\BackupEventLogs\app.evt")
```

This executes successfully with below output but the logs are not copied to C:\BackupEventLogs\ location

```
__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     :
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        :
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         :
__NAMESPACE      :
__PATH           : ReturnValue      : 0
```

Please help.

Comment: did you check if it was created as a hidden file?also `Win32_nteventlogfile` returns one object which is the log itself and not the actual events. so there is no need to do a `select`

Comment: Thanks Kiran.
could you tell me how do I get the actual events>get top 100>and save them in an evtx file .

Answer (score 0):

Filter left and save to CSV file

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NTLogEvent -Filter "logfile='Application'" |
   Select-Object -First 100 | 
      Export-CSV  c:\temp\appevents.csv -notype
```

Don`t think there is a way to export a subset of the messages to evtx. Seems its either all or  nothing. 
Do check [Wevtutil](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732848.aspx) which based on your OS may or may not be available.